# Equation alignment - linear equations

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, vertical-alignment

How can I produce the following equations with Latex? Note the alignment of terms in the linear equations and the "hints" to the right. I have tried using the ordinary `cases` by could not get the result I wanted without having `\` all over the place.

[image: perfectly aligned linear equations with hints]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Try to use `array` as you can see in solutions to many similar question here. And, can you show, what you try so far?

Comment: @Zarko Trust me, you don't want to see that mess :).

Comment: why not? ones I have been beginer too :-). at least I will not need to type your equation from scratch ...

Answer (score 4):

As starting point see if `array` can help ypu:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcrcrc@{\qquad}l}
-x  &   &       & + &   z   &   =   &   (a) \\
-2x & - &   y   & + &   5z  &   =   &   (b) \\
 2x & + &   y   &   &       &   =   &   (c)
\end{array}
\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Similar results you can obtain also with some other amsmath environments.

**Addendum:** probably you alo have problem how to align more equations. It seems that simple way is nested `array` environments:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
\begin{array}{rl}
                &
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcrcrc@{\qquad}l}
-x  &   &       & + &   z   &   =   &   (a) \\
-2x & - &   y   & + &   5z  &   =   &   (b) \\
 2x & + &   y   &   &       &   =   &   (c)
\end{array}
\right.         \\[5ex]
\Longleftrightarrow &
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcrcrc@{\qquad}l}
-x  &   &       & + &   z   &   =   &   (a) \\
-2x & - &   y   & + &   5z  &   =   &   (b) \\
 2x & + &   y   &   &       &   =   &   (c)
\end{array}
\right.         \\%
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your post sorry that I didn't post my code in time. I am still a bit ashamed of the ugliness of it.

Comment: well, mean time you received three nice solutions ...

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [systeme package](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/generic/systeme/systeme_doc_fr.pdf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}
\begin{document}

\systeme{-x    +  z =  3 @(a), 
        -2x -y + 5z = -1 @(b), 
         2x +y      =  1 @(c)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to align 3, -1 and -1 too?

Comment: @Clone  - Sure, add `\phantom{-}` as in Bernard's solution

Answer (score 2):

It's easy with the `systeme` package. Here are two variants:

```
\documentclass{article}%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{systeme}
\sysextracolsign{&}
\syscodeextracol{\kern2.5em$\mathrm\bgroup }{\egroup$}
\newcommand\phms{\phantom{-}}

\begin{document}

Here’s a first way: %
\begin{align*}
       & \systeme{-x + z = \phms3 & (a), -2x-y + 5z = -1 & (b), 2x + y =\phms 1 & (c)} \\
   \iff & \systeme{-x + z = \phms3 & (a') = (a), -y + 3z = -7 & (b') = (b)-2(a), 2x + y =\phms 7 & (c') = (c) + 2(a)} \\
   \iff & \systeme{-x + z = \phms3 & (a'') = (a'), -y + 3z = -7 & (b'') = (b'), 5z =\phms 0 & (c'') = (c') +(b')}
\end{align*}

Unless you prefer this: %
\begin{align*}
       & \systeme{-x + z = \phms3 & (a), -2x-y + 5z = -1 & (b), 2x + y =\phms 1 & (c)} \\
   ⇔ & \systeme{-x + z = \phms3 & \eqmakebox[b'][l]{$ \mathrm{(a')} $} = (a), \phantom{-2x}-y + 3z = -7 & \eqmakebox[b'][l]{$ \mathrm{(b')} $} = (b)-2(a), 2x + y =\phms 7 & \eqmakebox[b'][l]{$ \mathrm{(c')} $} = (c) + 2(a)} \\
   ⇔ & \systeme{-x + z = \phms3 & \eqmakebox[b''][l]{$ \mathrm{(a'')} $} = (a'), \phantom{-2x}-y + 3z = -7 & \eqmakebox[b''][l]{$ \mathrm{(b'')} $} = (b'), 5z =\phms 0 & \eqmakebox[b''][l]{$ \mathrm{(c'')} $} = (c') +(b')}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. The second one looks better since `=` are aligned in the equation part.  Is it possible to align `=` where it is a'=a b'=b and so on?

Comment: Not in a natural way (it's built-in as left-aligned), but I'll test an idea using another package. B.t.w;, do you want the second `=` aligned individually for each `\systeme` command?

Comment: @Clone: I've modified the second alignment code, to the `=` signs aligned for each `\systeme`. A global alignment wouldn't look very nice, in my opinion.